# bad_cast exception thrown when doing downcasting from Base class object by reference to derived class object

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, downcast

I still wonder why the following gives `std::bad_cast` exception

```
#include <typeinfo>
class A {virtual void fun() {}};
class B : public A {};
int main() {
    try { 
       A a; 
       B b = dynamic_cast<B&>(a);
    } catch (std::bad_cast& e) {
       std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

class `A` is a polymorphic class
class `B` is publicly derived from `A`
properly doing a downcast from base class `A` object through reference, `dynamic_cast` does accept a reference argument
but still why this exception?

Comment: Did you expect the cast operator to return a reference to a valid B object? Where could it find one?

Comment: `A a` is not a `B`, so the cast failure is the right behavior.

Comment: if you don't want an exception, cast it to a pointer instead of a reference, then check the return value against nullptr to see if the cast succeeded.

Answer (score 4):

This is what [dynamic_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) supposed to do. `a` is an object of `A` in fact, converting it to the derived class `B` would fail. On the other hand, if you convert something with type of reference or pointer to the base class, but refers to an object of `B` in fact, then it will work fine. e.g.

```
B b1;
A& ra = b1;
B b2 = dynamic_cast<B&>(ra);
```

Answer (score 3):

What you've basically said is "I have an animal, but is it a lion?"

And the language needs to be able to say either "yes it is a lion" or "no it is not a lion".

When you cast to a pointer type, it can say "no" by returning nullptr to you or the actual pointer to a lion if "yes"

However, there's no such thing as a null reference.   Because of this, when you cast to a reference, it needs a different mechanism to inform you that your animal isn't a lion.  It throws a bad cast exception in that case.